# Tentai Show: Unlikely travels

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, grid-deduction

My friend loves telling me her increasingly outlandish travel stories but I think this time she's gone a little too far and I'm not buying it. Can you tell which faraway land she wants me to think she visited this time?

Divide the grid into "rooms" among grid lines so that each room is 180° rotationally symmetrical and contains exactly one white or black circle, located in its centre. In the end, shade all rooms with a black circle in them.

<sub>Paraphrased from original rules on [Nikoli](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/astronomical_show.html)</sub>

[image: Empty Tentai Show grid]

[Solve on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/3nxr8zny)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your friend wants you to think she is in

> the [Land of Oz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_of_Oz)!

First, we mark the obvious lines

> [image: All obvious lines have been marked around the white and black circles]

Next, we notice that

> the top-right cell must go with the circle in the very middle. We trace a path and rotate around to get this
>  [image: More deductions, with all rooms being resolved]

Then we shade

> [image: Finished Puzzle, with OZ inside of the puzzle]
>  I don't see reason to doubt her.

Comment: Well that was fast, hehe. Nice job!

Comment: @Jafe I was introduced to Tentai Show by your Christmas-themed one last December and it became my goto pastime for several months. So I've had plenty of practice thanks to you :)

Comment: That's great to hear! Of course, the answer also refers to another place which might sound like an extremely unlikely travel destination to someone who didn't know it's also a nickname of an actual country :) Did you mean top left in spoiler box 3?

Comment: @Jafe Haha that didn't even cross my mind. I'll edit it in. And it was actually the top right corner I first noticed which quickly led to the others. I'll try to make that clearer too.

Comment: @Jafe at that stage the TL cell looked like it could have gone with one of the black dots so I left that part alone.